# SVN direct command output differs from scripted one

Tags: bash, svn

when I'm executing a command using Solaris 10 which updates ignores list it outputs properly like its supposed to be. However, when I want to do it automatically via bash script things go wrong, and an error pops up.
The command I execute is:

```
svn propset svn:ignore workspace/project/.settings
```

and the line executing it in the script:

```
svn propset svn:ignore -F $1/.settings $1/
```

where $1 is passed as workspace/project/

What I get in return in wrong scenario is:

> svn: The path 'workspace/project' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater
>   working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this
>   working copy.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two versions of Subversion installed, 1.7 and 1.6 or older. When you execute the script yourself, you're executing the 1.7 client, and your script is calling the 1.6 version.

Find the older version and remove it from the system, or determine the correct path to the 1.7 version and specify it explicitly in the script.

Comment: The 'svn --version' executed under the script returns 1.7 as well. Should it be 1.6 if thats the version used by the script?

Comment: That depends - is it the same *user* that's executing the script, in the same environment (same `$PATH`, for example)?

Comment: Nvm, fixed. SVN was just an alias to a differen version, and It could have been overlapping with the installed one. Ive just passed an absolute path to the SVN i wanted to use in the script.